# Palette parameter in fviz_pca_biplot cannot change the palette

Tags: r, pca, factoextra

The palette parameter in *fviz_pca_biplot* function (from *factoextra* package) can't change the colors. I have added *habillage* parameter, and function works correctly, except colors.
Is this a bug, or I don't understand the function? The same parameter works perfectly with *fviz_pca_ind*.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on what you would you like to be colored? In both fviz_pca_biplot  and fviz_pca_ind, the observations are colored with the habillage parameter.

Comment: Tried the grey palette. Habillage parameter works excellent, but the colors doesn't appeal to me. Eventually, I figure out with `+ scale_color_grey()` since fviz_pca_biplot relies on ggplot. Thanks